# data.table aggregate not select NA

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate, na

I want to do an aggregation and different actions per column. How could I select the first non NA argument. I found a way, but I think it could be done on a more efficient way:

```
test <- data.table(A = c(NA,NA,1), B = c(1,2,3),C = c(NA,NA,1), D = c(1,2,2))
test[,list(A = A[!is.na(A)][1], B = max(B), C = C[!is.na(C)][1]), by = D]
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this, I have to do this on a very large set many times.

Comment: Try `test[order(D, -B), head(.SD, 1) , by = D]`

Comment: This works for like one colum but I want to do the action on more columns

Comment: If you have separate functions on different columns, what is wrong with your approach

Comment: Mmh maybe nothing but I thought maybe there is a better function to select one element which is not NA. This feels like doing something not efficient because is.na loops through all the elements while he could stop when he founds the first element that is not NA.

Comment: In the devel version `test[, c(B = max(B), lapply(.SD, function(x) x[!is.na(x)][1])), D, .SDcols = c('A', 'C')]`

Comment: That does not work could not find object B and if define object B in .SDcols I do not get the right output

Comment: I said in the development version (it works for me - 1.9.7+)

Answer (score 0):

If you're after speed, you can always go down the C++ route, which is faster, but not dramatically so. I modified @akrun's code so that it worked in the current release:

```
op <- function(d) d[,list(A = A[!is.na(A)][1], B = max(B), C = C[!is.na(C)][1]), by = D]
akrun_m <- function(d) d[, c(B = max(B), lapply(mget(c('A', 'C')), function(x) x[!is.na(x)][1])), by = D]

library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('double firstnum(NumericVector vec){
int n = vec.size();
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
   if (!R_IsNA(vec[i])) {
     return vec[i];
   }
}
}
')

seb <- function(d) d[,c(B = max(B), lapply(mget(c('A', 'C')), firstnum)), by = D]
```

Now to benchmarking:

```
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(123)

> microbenchmark(op(test), akrun_m(test), seb(test))
Unit: microseconds
          expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
      op(test) 647.881 669.5210 697.4699 687.1600 725.3510  949.747   100
 akrun_m(test) 691.242 723.5915 759.8265 758.3305 786.0095  906.734   100
     seb(test) 543.220 561.7975 624.5136 583.3550 606.9620 1816.716   100

n <- 1000000
test2 <- data.table(A = sample(c(0:9, NA), n, replace = TRUE),
                    B = sample(c(0:9), n, replace = TRUE),
                    C = sample(c(0:9, NA), n, replace = TRUE),
                    D = sample(c(0:9), n, replace = TRUE))

> microbenchmark(op(test2), akrun_m(test2), seb(test2))
Unit: milliseconds
           expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
      op(test2) 24.19831 25.66229 29.12567 26.53464 27.04707 77.30163   100
 akrun_m(test2) 24.61977 25.95137 29.35343 26.88825 27.32421 85.68336   100
     seb(test2) 15.94157 17.19831 18.75357 17.70207 18.04410 69.51589   100
```

You can see the C++ implementation is faster, but not dramatically so.